# cp: cannot create regular file '/.kaggle/': Not a directory

Tags: google-colaboratory, kaggle

I am trying to access all Kaggle datasets in Google Colab for machine learning works.I have uploaded Kaggle API named Kaggle.json to Colab file. and I installed Kaggle using

```
 !pip install -q Kaggle
```

And to add .json file in ~/.Kaggle/ directory I run following in cell to create Kaggle folder in colab file structure.
!mkdir -p ~/.Kaggle/
And I try to place Kaggle.json inside /.Kaggle/  running following cell

```
!cp kaggle.json /.kaggle/
```

But it throws me error as shown below:

```
cp: cannot create regular file '/.kaggle/': Not a directory
```

Above method is illustrated in kaggle forum https://www.kaggle.com/general/51898 .But it doesn't works for me. Do you have any idea what's wrong is going with above implementation.Please Help me to solve this.

Thank you

Comment: `mkdir -p ~/.Kaggle/` but `cp kaggle.json /.kaggle/` - unixy systems are usually case-sensitive, so those are two different names. Try `mkdir -p ~/.kaggle/` instead...

Comment: Thank you  for highlighting my mistakes in case sensitivity. Yes these are case-sensitive. But even I  run `!cp kaggle.json /.Kaggle/` instead of `!cp kaggle.json /.kaggle/` It throws same result `cp: cannot create regular file '/.Kaggle/': Not a directory`. And trying `mkdir -p ~/.kaggle/`  followed by `!cp kaggle.json /.kaggle/` also not helps me and returns same result.Note:All case-sensitivity are well considered.